# wordpress pagination problem with page templates

Tags: pagination

just now i found that pagination depends on permalink structure.I am using wp 3.8 version.
For pagination in page template I used

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=1& post_type=product &paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```

For paginating

```
  <?php
  global $wp_query;

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

  echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
'prev_next'    => False,

    ) );
    ?>
```

I have noticed that for default permalink structure pagination works fine but if i change permalink structure it no longer works.It shows first page result but on next pagination it moves to index.php

Why?

Comment: When click a next page link and it goes to index.php, it might be there is no page 2 in the query. If you don't have a 404 page, WordPress will fallback to index.php instead. Could you paste more code for us to see what's happening?

Comment: But when I changed permalink structure to default it works.